# how to resolve segmentation fault in mongo-cxx-driver's bsoncxx::to_json

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

I am using mongo-cxx-driver r3.9.0 version.
simple code of creating a document and logging the document using bsoncxx::to_json is throwing segmentation fault.

stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007f6108ce27d8 in bson_get_data () from /usr/local/lib64/libbson-1.0.so.0
#1  0x00007f6108ce3af0 in bson_as_json_with_opts () from /usr/local/lib64/libbson-1.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f6108ce3d32 in bson_as_json () from /usr/local/lib64/libbson-1.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f610bb3dbdf in bsoncxx::v_noabi::(anonymous namespace)::to_json_helper(bsoncxx::v_noabi::document::view, char* (*)(_bson_t const*, unsigned long*)) ()
   from /usr/local/lib64/libbsoncxx.so._noabi
#4  0x00007f610bb3dcb4 in bsoncxx::v_noabi::to_json[abi:cxx11](bsoncxx::v_noabi::document::view, bsoncxx::v_noabi::ExtendedJsonMode) () from /usr/local/lib64/libbsoncxx.so._noabi
```

query is created using following lines.

```
    namespace bbs = bsoncxx::builder::stream;
    namespace bd = bsoncxx::document;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_array;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;
    using bbs::open_document;
    using bbs::close_document;
    using bbs::finalize;

    bbs::document eq_builder = bbs::document{};
    eq_builder << kUpdatedAtField << last_read_timestamp_
               << kIdField << open_document << "$gt" << last_query_id_
               << close_document << finalize;
    bbs::document gt_builder = bbs::document{};
    gt_builder << kUpdatedAtField << open_document << "$gt"
               << last_read_timestamp_
               << close_document
               << finalize;
    bd::view query = make_document(kvp("$or", make_array(eq_builder.view(), gt_builder.view())));
    LOG(INFO) << "query generated " << bsoncxx::to_json(query);
```

the last line, where I try to log is throwing segmentation fault.

How can I resolve this? Not sure if I am doing anything wrong while compiling the document.

Comment: Based on the stack trace it looks like there is no data - bson_get_data.
Maybe try executing the query first and if there are results - try converting those results to json.

Comment: this is just the query document.
even before executing the query driver is throwing segmnetation fault. to understand how the query is generated logged the query and its failing at log line itself.

Comment: bson encoding is working if i use bsoncxx::builder::basic::document. 
bsoncxx::builder::stream is throwing errors.

Comment: Maybe there is nothing in the stream - which would cause conversion to json errors.
I suggest creating the query manually - and running it manually to verify it works - or use a debugger in Visual Studio Code if there is one for code using mongo-cxx-driver.

Comment: The line before converting the query to json, invoked make_document. Its definitely not empty.

Comment: When something like this happens to me it is because the document is invalid JSON. Either empty or the document itself is invalid JSON. I suggest writing out the results you are getting and checking the results are valid JSON.